# Visual Studio 2008 give error of component not found

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm been using VS 2008 "forever". Rebooted yesterday and now I get an error that says a component can not be found. Reinstall application.

I've reinstalled, I've uninstalled and installed VS2008 twice and still get the same error.

Searching on the net shows people having a similar problem with a missing alt dll, but I don't have VC++ loaded and that dll is not missing.  Have ran the depends.exe and the only missing dll is dwmapi.dll, which isn't even needed on a Windows XP os.  Tried using /safemode and it still fails.

I need some more ideas or a way to find out what exactly is missing.

Thanks
Dwight

Comment: Does it tell you which component it thinks is missing?  Perhaps try logging (`devenv.exe /Log [logfile]`) and see what jewels that uncovers.

Comment: Does the error show when devenv is started?  Or, when a project/solution file is opened?

Comment: The error happens when devenv is started. Click ok on the message and denenv closes.

Comment: Unfortunately the log is never created.

Answer (score 1):

Before you try anything else, I would suggest that you try a quick [**system restore**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306084) back to the day before yesterday if that's possible.  If it works, it might save you lots of time trying to troubleshoot it.

Comment: To much has been done to do that.